# ¿Como puedo mostrar los decimales de la division?

Tags: c#, double, division

El programa que tengo escrito no me guarda (supongo) los decimales de una división o por lo menos al mostrarlo el resultado solo me muestra el primer número que seria el entero.
sera que necesito declararla de alguna manera especial?, igual la división es de dos datos que tengo declarado como enteros.

```
int num1= 24;
int num2=25;

double num3 = num1/num2;

dgvFrecuencia.Rows.Add(num3);
```

es algo así lo que tengo hecho y cuando lo quiero mostrar en mi tabla únicamente me muestra 0 cuando debería de ser 0.96 y no encuentro como hacer que me aparezca los resultados con los decimales y asi me pasa con los otros datos que tengo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta castear el resultado amigo.

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
`double num3 = (double)num1/num2;`
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya me funciona el programa como yo quiero. Enserio muchas gracias